# How can I do an UPDATE from table to another?

Tags: sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I use this Query inside the table wp_term_taxonomy to update bettwen 2 taxonomy :

update wp_term_taxonomy 
set taxonomy = 'selary' 
where taxonomy = 'series'

what if I want to update meta_value from wp_postmeta to wp_term_taxonomy taxonomy !

Can you please help me with this problem?

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to update a table from another.

```
UPDATE table2 
SET table2.col1 = table1.col1, 
table2.col2 = table1.col2,
...
FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table1.id = table2.id
```

It would be good if you can provide table schema and sample data.